# Queue<T> type with Entity Framework Cast error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, queue

I have an entity A which holds a `Queue<XYZ>` B property. I want to persist it in a MySQL database. When migrating, the table is created correctly - each entity A has a table depicting `Queue<XYZ>` B. However, when I want to query the data from the database using:

```cs
A entityA = await _context.A.Include(entityA => entityA.B).FirstOrDefaultAsync((...));
```

Then I get such an error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type  'System.Collections.Generic.Queue'1[API.Models.XYZ]' to type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'1[API.Models.XYZ]'.

When I change the `Queue<XYZ>` B to `List<XYZ>` B then it works fine.

Is it impossible to automatically persist a queue to a database with Entity Framework?
Or do I have to do some extra work?

Comment: Can you add the definition of Entity A and Entity B?

Comment: First question should be: why do you want it to be a queue? Note that the order of items will never be guaranteed when EF populates a list.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an entity A which holds a Queue B property. I want to
> persist it in a MySQL database. When migrating, the table is created
> correctly - each entity A has a table depicting Queue B. However,
> when I want to query the data from the database using:
>
> `A entityA = await _context.A.Include(entityA => entityA.B).FirstOrDefaultAsync((...));`

According to your description and the query statement, I have created a DeparmentViewModel with the Queue property, and reproduced the error when query the database using EF core.

```
public class DepartmentViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int DepId { get; set; }
    public string DepName { get; set; }
    public Queue<EmployeeViewModel> EmployeeViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

To solve this issue, it seems that we could re-generate a Queue object based on the query result, like this:

```
        DepartmentViewModel queryresult = _context.DepartmentViewModels
            .Include(c=>c.EmployeeViewModels)
            .Where(c => c.DepId==2) //
            .Select(c=> new DepartmentViewModel()
            {
                DepId = c.DepId,
                DepName = c.DepName,
                EmployeeViewModels = new Queue<EmployeeViewModel>(c.EmployeeViewModels.ToList())
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Besides, I also found that if using the Queue, when insert new data, it might cause the following error:

"*System.InvalidOperationException: 'The type of navigation property 'EmployeeViewModels' on the entity type 'DepartmentViewModel' is 'Queue' which does not implement ICollection. Collection navigation properties must implement ICollection<> of the target type.'*"

So, in my opinion, when you create Navigation Properties, try to use `List<T>` or `ICollection<T>`, instead of using `Queue<T>`.